# how do you store a date type in a variable? Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

So lets say Im declaring variables so I can later insert values into them

```
DECLARE
max_number NUMBER (2,2)
the_date DATE() /*********** how do you store a date?  */
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(invoice_total), invoice_date
INTO max_number, the_date
FROM.................
```

How do I store a date value into a variable? what goes into the parenthesis for `the_date`? I am a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. `DATE` is a data type, it is not further qualified by scale and precision (like `NUMBER`) or length (like `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2`). There aren't even any parentheses after `DATE`. You just declare `the_date DATE`, that's all.

By the way, when you declare `max_number`, you don't have to specify scale and precision; you may, but you don't have to. `declare max_number NUMBER, the_date DATE` suffices.